# Can I use "dont descend" SMB parameter on a directory path, preferably using a glob?

Tags: server-message-block, smb-conf

I have a samba share where I want to use `dont descend` on multiple descendent directories.  The samba share `path=/home`.  Every directory in home for this particular server is a website (this is a web server). Each website has a directory I want to apply `dont descend` to.  Due to the nature of the server, I can't just add a new path every time a new website is spun up.  Ideally I would like to use this (to prevent descent into "dir"):

```
dont descend = */public/dir
```

That doesn't work obviously.  It's my understanding that `/` is the delimiter for this property.  I have tried just using a path (both glob and non).  I have tried seeing if a variable (`%m` or whatever) would work.  I have not found a suitable variable.  I can't use veto because the particular files I want excluded have a hashed name without an extension.

In summary my question(s) is/are:

**Can I use a path for `dont descend`?** and
**Can I use globbing (`*` or `%` variable) to target multiple directories?**

My samba config for this particular share is as follows:

```
[Websites]
    path=/home
    browsable=yes
    writable=yes
    create mask = 0755
    force directory mode = 2775

    ;inherit permissions=yes    
    inherit owner=yes
    acl group control=yes

    veto files = /._*/.DS_Store/.TemporaryItems/
    delete veto files = yes 

    wide links = yes 
    follow symlinks = yes
```